# Mock call to method from another method within same controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, mockery

I'm calling the endpoint that routes to `methodIWantToTest` like so:

```
$response = $this->json('GET', 'my/endpoint/');
```

I'm attaching the code below, any ideas how I can mock the call to the second method?
 Thanks.

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function methodIWantToTest():
    {
        //some code to test  
        $this->methodIWantToMock()
        //some more code to test
    }
    public function methodIWantToMock():
    {
        //mock this response
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly but you're already doing it.
I don't know also why you're using ':' after the '()' in function and you need semicolon after you call the method you want to call

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function methodIWantToTest()
    {
        //some code to test  
        $this->methodIWantToMock();
        //some more code to test
    }
    public function methodIWantToMock()
    {
        //mock this response
    }
}
```

you can also pass value if you want just do this

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function methodIWantToTest()
    {
        //some code to test  
        $this->methodIWantToMock($value);
        //some more code to test
    }
    public function methodIWantToMock($value)
    {
        //mock this response
    }
}
```